# How can i allow user with admin role to edit the role of the other users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, roles

I use devise for authentication and only an admin can create a user.

I use cancan to assign roles to the user during user creation.

I want the admin to view all the users roles and **the admin should be able to edit the roles of the users.**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/marklocklear/devise_multi_tentant. In ability.rb I have...

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :manage, :all if user.role == "admin"
  end
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972280/how-can-a-user-with-same-role-can-access-different-posts-with-different-permissi I have also posted one more in the above link please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a role attributes for User model.
   Then, when user go to admin dashboard, you can check user's role. If user isn't admin, redirect to another page (using `before_filter :function`)
2. But, instead doing everything manually, you can use gem `cancan` instead, it's so popular and easy to use!
   You can find the document here: [GitHub](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)
   Or in rails cast [episodes 192](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)

Basically, it'll create a ability model, and you will declare privilege for user, a sample ability class

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :update, User
    end
 end
end
```

After that, you can authorize for user in action, controller or views, like the example [see this link](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities)

PS: sorry if my English was too bad, thanks:)

Comment: He said he is already using cancan to assign roles...not sure this answers his question...