# How can a user with same role access different posts with different permissions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, roles, access-control

I use devise for authentication and have assigned a role for each user. I have one more model `posts` which contain number of posts. I want to restrict one user of the role `employee` to view the specific post and the same user to view and create the different post. How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout CanCan :) https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: i have already assigned a role for user using cancan but what i ask is something different.

Comment: Then could you please elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i have post model with few fields like message, posted_by, posted_date etc.. I have already assigned a role for the user. I want to display the posts posted by the users and he should be able to view the posts of other persons as well but the user should be able to edit or destroy only the posts that were posted by him.

Comment: Checkout the section under resources on the CanCan wiki: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/CanCan-2.0

Shout if you need any help on it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I am late to the battle here.

What you are looking for is an extension to role-based access control. RBAC cannot cater well for your scenario. You need to consider attribute-based access control. CanCan and Devise are two language-specific frameworks that address attribute-based access control.

If you want a broader, more generic ABAC solution, then consider XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language, which is a standard defined by OASIS much like SAML is.

XACML gives you:

- attribute-based access control: attributes can be used to describe pretty much anything (users, objects, resources, context, time, actions...).
- policy-based access control: policies bring together attributes to define authorization. For instance *employees can view the posts of employees in the same team and can edit posts they own*.
- fine-grained access: it is possible to define very specific and granular authorization policies
- support for segregation of duty
- language-independent authorization: it works for Java, .NET, Ruby, Python, and more...
- centralized policy management

Here are some interesting resources to learn more:

- NIST [RBAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/) model
- NIST [ABAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/) model
- OASIS [XACML](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) website

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial which specify the ability to define logic to control the user activity

https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Using-rolify-with-Devise-and-Authority